# A not free $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851182/if-m-i-i-in-i-is-a-family-of-r-modules-free-then-the-product-prod?rq=1) I see that $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not a free abelian group. Someone can explain me why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you click the link in your link?

Comment: I don't understand the concept of dual then I don't understand why the problem in the link implies what I am asking.

Comment: There is not other way? Or, What I need to understand this prove?

Comment: @Alex: The link doesn't prove $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is free. And despite the phrasing of the answer in that link, the link in the answer in that link doesn't prove $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is free either. Although the question is about a fact that I imagine could be used in a (nontrivial) proof it's not free.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/10249 to 
[Is it true that, as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, the polynomial ring and the power series ring over integers are dual to each other?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-ring-ove) on MathOverflow shows that
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{Z})
$$ 
is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}$.

If $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ were free it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ for some infinite set $X$, so we'd have
$$
\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}\cong
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{Z})\cong
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^{(X)},\mathbb{Z})\cong
\mathbb{Z}^X
$$
which is false because the first group is countable, whereas the final one isn't.

---

There are different proofs of the result above. An abelian group $L$ is called *slender* if, for every homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}\to L$, $f(e_n)=0$ for all but a finite number of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (where $e_n$ is the function which is $1$ on $n$ and $0$ elsewhere).

A theorem by Nunke (Acta Sci. Math. Szeged, **23** (1962)) characterizes slender groups:

> An abelian group $L$ is slender if and only if
>
> - $L$ is reduced and torsionfree and
> - $L$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ or to the group of $p$-adic integers for any prime $p$.

(I'm pretty sure you can find a proof of Nunke's theorem in Fuchs's *Infinite Abelian Groups*.)

In particular $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ is slender for any countable set $X$. A property of slender groups is the following.

> If $L$ is a slender group, $(G_n)$ is a countable family of torsionfree abelian groups and $f\colon \prod_n G_n\to L$ is a homomorphism, then
>
> - $f(G_n)=0$ for all but a finite number of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (the canonical embedding of $G_n$ in the product is considered)
> - $f$ is zero if and only if it is zero on $\bigoplus_n G_n$ (considered as a subgroup of the product).

A consequence of this is that for every homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}\to L$ a slender group, the image of $f$ is finitely generated.

So, since $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ is slender, no homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}\to\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ is surjective, which proves $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not free.

Comment: What should I read to understand this explanation?

Comment: @YotasTrejos What is that you're not understanding?

Comment: I can try to unsdertand the demostration in MO. Your argument is clear to me, the post in MO is not. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand in the post in MO the use of p-adic numbers.